# S3 bucketpolicy and EMR - example

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I can not find example of S3 BucketPolicy that allows only EMR to read data from it. EMR would be in the same account as S3. Anyone has any example to share?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work.

```json
{
  "Id": "Policy1590853624822",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1590853616750",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:1234567890:cluster/*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can create your own policies [here in aws policy generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

Comment: Deny is more important than an Allow. This policy would block everyone, your "allowed" principal included.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for noticing. Will fix it